# Python: ProjectEuler Q.5

Tags: python

I'm trying to solve the following question: What is the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20? The problem is that I get a `MemoryError`. Is there a better way to do this, **using the same logic**?

```
for n in range(1,1000000000):
    count = 0
    for i in range(1,21):
        if n%i == 0:
            count = count + 1
            if count == 20:
                print n
```

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python 3.1 - Memory Error during sampling of a large list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706151/python-3-1-memory-error-during-sampling-of-a-large-list)

Comment: Ideally you'd never want to implement the logic that you have.  It probably defeats the objective of the problem.  You could optimize the solution without too much effort.

Comment: @devnull that's python 3, and moreover while the question is similar the answers are way too specific IMO and would not likely help OP.

Comment: Namely, taking the numbers 1...20 and finding their [gcd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor), from there it's rather trivial.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum (1) I did not stop you from posting an answer.  (2) While the referenced duplicate might contain "Python 3" in the title, this _problem_ has been asked and answered well over a few hundred times on SO.

Comment: @devnull I completely agree. However, I could not find a good duplicate (which is why I answered). If you find one that resembles this problem close enough, I'll gladly close vote.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I'm not sure what you mean by a _good duplicate_.  Whether you opt to close it or not is your wish.  There are no rules that prevent one from posting an answer to an obvious duplicate, neither is one obliged to vote to close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using Python 2, `range` allocates a list.

Utilize Python's lazy abilities with generators* , and use `xrange` instead.

```
for n in xrange(1,1000000000):
    count = 0
    for i in xrange(1,21):
        if n%i == 0:
            count = count + 1
            if count == 20:
                print n
```

That should solve your memory error. That said, there is a much faster solution to that particular problem (however, you asked for 'using the same logic').

<sub>* actually, a sequence object</sub>